# Use 'custom' parameters in function, for entry widget (GTK#)

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#

Is there a way that I am able to use 'custom' parameters with a function that is used when the value in an entry widget is changed.

the basic function is:

```
    public void(object sender, EventArgs args){
        Entry ent1 = (Entry)sender;
    }
```

what I tried:

```
    public void onChange(object sender, EventArgs args, String name){
        Entry ent1 = (Entry)sender;
    }
```

but It would run, because when I was calling the function it was:
    entry1 += onChange("testname");

which only passes one paramter to the function, when it needs three.
What I'm asking is how can I use a 'custom' paramter like 'name', and still pass the values for 'sender' and 'args'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a delegate that wraps code that passes that extra parameter.

You should be able to do it with this syntax:

```
entry1 += (s, e) => onChange(s, e, "testname");
```

However, this will make you unable to unsubscribe that event. If you need that, you will have to store the delegate:

```
ChangeEventHandler onchange = (s, e) => onChange(s, e, "testname");
entry1 += onchange;
...
entry1 -= onchange;
```